# Is there a way to deterministically get a txHash (rather than the safeTxHash) for a given safe transaction before that safe transaction is executed?

Tags: gnosis-safe, gnosis

I have been trying different ways of doing this with ethers such as attempting to form a transaction object with populateTransaction on the execTransaction function in the Safe contract for signing and getting different Safe error codes like GS030.

Is this possible in some way?

Comment: Not sure to fully understand what you want to do / have tried ? Could you post some code ?

Comment: I am populating all the necessary fields for a txHash such as chainId, nonce, gasPrice, gasLimit, to, value, data (formed by populate transaction on the execTransaction function). Then serializing this transaction, signing this transaction, and hashing the full result of this but it never is the same as the txHash from the transaction actually submitted.